# How is Falcon-Heavy staged?

Tags: falcon-heavy

How are the boosters attached to the core at the aft end?  How do they separate?

Comment: can you check to see if your question is answered in answer(s) to [What is used to connect the side boosters to the first stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25009/12102) or perhaps [Are Falcon Heavy's side boosters aerodynamically detached?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24892/12102) or possibly [What would the challenges be in developing a Falcon Heavy with three or four strap-on boosters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17256/12102)
Thanks!

Comment: SpaceX puts an incredible amount of info on their website.  Have you looked there?